# Calculate Average Score on Repeated Measures with Uneven Sample Sizes

Tags: mean

I am currently evaluating the predictive validity of a set of personnel selection procedures (predictor) on subsequent vocational training outcomes (criterion).

As far as the criterion variables are concerned, subjects are repeatedly graded 1 to 4 on a total of 9 distinct dimensions during 7 successive training events. I have tried running correlations between my predictor variables and each individual set of grades for each individual training event (i.e. all scores obtained for each dimension on the first training event, then all scores for each dimension on the second training event, etc.). This doesn't do much as the variance in the scores for each dimension within one individual training event is absolutely minimal (the majority of scores are 3's, with the occasional 4 and no 1's or 2's whatsoever).

Therefore, I have decided to consider the traits that are being measured (i.e. the dimensions that are being graded) to be relatively stable in time and would like to use a "grand-average" score across all 7 training events as my criterion variable (to generate some much needed variance). However, that's where I am having some trouble.

In fact, I have a total of 110 subjects in the sample, of which 80 have completed all 7 training events, and 30 have only completed 5. I have observed some very interesting and conceptually relevant correlations after just calculating a grand average score per dimension for each subject in the sample. But I think I might have generated some artificial variance, since I averaged a total of 7 scores for 80 people, and only a total of 5 scores for the remaining 30 people.

With this in mind, my question is the following: is there any way I can format my data so that the averages for both the people who have completed 7 training runs and those who have only completed 5 become "equivalent" or "weighted" in a sense ? I do fully understand that they will never be equivalent on the conceptual plane (since 30 people have 2 training runs missing, and therefore we do not know the "real" way it would have played out). My goal is to have one single variable for each dimension I can use as a criterion, averaged for every participant across all training runs they completed (even if some of them have only completed 5 instead of 7).

Many thanks in advance and please feel free to let me know should you require more information!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a number of measurements of the same individuals, you should be fine averaging their measurements along each of the 9 dimensions. One possible issue is that you may have more variance in the 5-trial averages versus the 7-trial averages. That could cause non-constant variance (though it sounds like your data exhibit very little variance).

A way to handle non-constant variance is to do a weighted regression that stabilizes the variances. You would weight the 5-trial data by some weight that is 5/7 the weight used on the 7-trial data. (So you could use a weight of 5 for 5-trial data and 7 for 7-trial data.)

Finally, you should consider why some of the individuals only completed 5 trials. There might be a lower mean score or some other difference between individuals who completed all trials and those who only completed 5 trials.

Comment: Hello and many thanks for the prompt response. I just split up the sample into two independent groups depending on number of training runs completed (g1 with 7 runs n=80, g2 with 5 runs n=30) and ran both Mann-Whitney U and Levene's test to compare means and variances for each dimension based on grouping. MW tells me that means differ between the 2 groups on 1 single dimension out of 9. Levene's test however indicated that variances significantly differ between groups on 7 out of 9 dimensions. I guess this is akin to what you were expecting.

Comment: With regards to why 30 individuals only completed 5 trials, it is simply because they haven't been with the company long enough to have gone through the full 7 runs (trainings are scheduled approx. every 6 months, so they are one year "behind" the others).

Comment: What I don't quite understand is your suggestion of going for a weighted regression. Would that be a way to transform my data so I can run the desired rank correlations with the appropriate weighting built in to the different variables?

Comment: (My apologies for the multiple comments, I had to split them up due to character limitations. I am not quite familiar with the site)

Comment: Weighted regression would not transform your data; it would just put more weight on the less noisy observations. I do worry about the difference between your two groups: they differ along one dimension and if time with the firm is a factor, then your 5-trial group could include people who will be fired between trials 5 and 7 -- while the 7-trial group are people who were not fired. That means your 7-trial sample is not representative of employees just hired or with the firm for a shorter amount of time.

Comment: Hello again. Unfortunately, I believe that is not what I am looking for. Since I will have to run bi-variate correlations first and foremost, I am looking for a way to "neutralize" the differences in the sample sizes' influence on the averages for each dimension, which I am looking to use as a criterion variable. I have since contacted a colleague of mine, who simply advised to dismiss the missing data points for trials 6 and 7 and to carry on with the averages I do already have (since the things being graded in trials 6 and 7 do not conceptually differ from those in 1-5). What do you think?

Comment: Also, with regards to time with the firm as a factor: considering that the firm has a close to zero failure rate in training (and therefore a similar rate of leave, forced or otherwise), I believe that this consideration could be irrelevant. What we are doing by averaging the 7 data points is looking at the average performance of employees during their first year and a half with the company. I was quite unclear when I said that they are scheduled every six months. Actually it is three in quick succession, then two after 6 months, and two another six months later. My apologies for that.

Comment: Dismissing the missing points is a common "solution." However, that is not defensible when (1) you have shown there is a difference between the two groups, and (2) we can *easily* imagine a mechanism that makes the two groups different in terms of ability. As for the failure rate in training, it may be close to zero but that is not zero and even a small failure rate could skew the results. While having tests at 0, 6, and 12 months is better than across 7 years, you still have lots of potential for differences between those two groups. Hence no surprise that you found they are different.

Comment: Considering your feedback as well as the one I received from yet another colleague, we have decided to reduce our sample to the 75% for whom we have 5 trials available. We agreed on keeping our study design as clean as possible, and still get to keep some interesting correlations at least. Many thanks for your sensible feedback! I guess I should close the question, then?

Comment: That may be good. Just keep your eyes out for ways in which the 5- and 7-trial groups differ. Who knows? You might discover something that gives you an early diagnostic for employee performance. Sounds like you are on your way. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Only fully specified full likelihood models will correctly take into account varying numbers of measurements, and this and all methods being discussed require a *missing at random* assumption.  Your Y is ordinal so I suggest a longitudinal ordinal model, either using a Markov process or subject random effects.  These are detailed [here](https://hbiostat.org/proj/covid19).  It is usually best to analyze the rawest form of the data rather than taking averages first.  There is some power gain from using all the individual measurements.